# Connect failed when installed PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, pear

I had a problem when installed PHPUnit, i couldn't open a connection when used pear channel-discover (website pear.phpunit.de is normal and i still use channel-info or clear-cache normally). I tried many ways but failed.

I hope a help from you,

Thank everyone very much,

Command line: pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

Error: **...Connection to 'pear.phpunit.de:80' failed: A connection attempt...because connected host has failed to respond**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `pear` distribution for `phpunit` anymore.

The only valid day to install it these days is [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Here are the [instructions](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer) on how to do that.

Relevant Sebastian Bergmann tweets:

- https://twitter.com/s_bergmann/status/539426863375212544
- https://twitter.com/s_bergmann/status/539427096750481408

Comment: Great! I used PHPUnit that downloaded from phpunit.de and PHPUnit Skeleton without use PEAR. Thank you.